# Best practice for multi usage of socket.io in an application?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Something like if Facebook uses socket.io. So they need a lot of socket to handle.

Such as New Feed, Private message, Group message.
And data need to be sent to the right person. Can anyone explain me how they handle this ? Maybe some code or pictures of workflow.

Thanks.